# setting DHCP on an interface when it comes UP

Tags: macos, network, tethering

When I tether my MacBook Pro via USB-C cable to my Linux mobile device, in MacOS an interface `en7` gets created on the fly. The mobile runs a NetworkManager with a DHCP server part. I can use the command `sudo ipconfig set en7 DHCP` and this brings an IP addr 10.42.0.18 into this interface (the mobile, which acts now as AP to Internet, has 10.42.0.1 and sets up everything incl. routing and NAT).

How this ipconfig can be done automatically when the interface comes up?

DHCP does not start by its own on the tethered interface:

not tethered:

```
$ ifconfig en7
ifconfig: interface en7 does not exist
```

now connected via USB-C, but no IP addr:

```
$ ifconfig en7
en7: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=404<VLAN_MTU,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 76:c9:f8:13:92:ad
    inet6 fe80::4d7:4e33:5efb:bd33%en7 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x13
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (2500Base-T <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

now DHCP is set with ipconfig:

```
$ sudo ipconfig set en7 DHCP


$ ifconfig en7
en7: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=404<VLAN_MTU,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 76:c9:f8:13:92:ad
    inet6 fe80::4d7:4e33:5efb:bd33%en7 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x13
    inet 10.42.0.253 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.42.0.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (2500Base-T <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

```
$ ssh purism@10.42.0.1

Linux pureos 6.4.0-1-librem5 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct  6 00:42:44 UTC 2023 aarch64

You have mail.
Last login: Wed Nov 22 06:54:33 2023 from 192.168.178.50
inhibiting suspend ...
purism@pureos:~$
```

Comment: Generally speaking if macOS sees a new active network it will, first, look for a DHCP server before self-assigning one to itself. However you may need to add your USB device as a network device manually (once) and set its config to DHCP. Once that is done it should all be automatic, I believe...

Comment: No, DHCP does not start automatically on the Mac, see my edited post.